# How to upload a file while running tests in selenium hub

Tags: selenium

I am testing a web application using selenium and as part of the test i need to upload a document. When I click on a button called '`filelabel`' it opens up a windows-based-pop up when the user can browse to the id and click open and then the doc gets attached. I am using chrome driver.

I have tried 2 approaches

1. `Autoit` :  when i run the test locally, I have created an exe and the test runs successfully. But i need to run the test in selenium hub through a Jenkin build and i do not have permission to run exe. Getting permission denied error
2. Tried the remote file upload using the below code and ended up with `'unable to focus element;'` exception. I think the control is not being transfered to the window based pop up and hence i am getting this exception

//remote upload

```
driver.findElement(By.name("fileLabel")).click();
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.name("fileLabel"));

logger.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "filelabel found", "file label found");

upload.sendKeys("./datafiles/myid.jpg");

logger.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "id uploaded", "id uploaded");
```

3. I have also read about using the robo class. but again it looks like i will have to pass the absolute path. not sure whether it will work in the hub

the file is not getting uploaded. I am looking for a viable solution to get the file uploaded while running the test in selenium hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue using approach 2. I was getting unable to focus element exception since i was not clicking on the element with type=file.

then used the below code

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("idDocumentFile"));
String currPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File imgFile = new File(currPath +"/datafiles/myid.pdf");
upload.sendKeys(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```